# Show estimators of P(X=0) for X~POISSON are biased/unbiased

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Poi}(\mu)$ and $\theta = \Pr[X=0] = e^{-\mu}$.

1. Show that $\tilde{\theta} = u(X)$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ where $u(0) = 1, u(x) = 0$, for $x=1,2,3,\ldots$
2. Is $\hat{\theta} = e^{-x}$ unbiased for $\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(1)$, the expectation of $u(X)$ is trivial to calculate. It is simply $(1)(\Pr(X=0)$, that is, $e^{-\mu}$. Thus $u(X)$ is an unbiased estimator of $e^{-\mu}$.

For $(2)$, we find $E(e^{-X})$. This is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^k}{k!}$. Express this as $e^{-\mu}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(e^{-1}\mu)^k}{k!}$.

We recognize that the sum  is the power series expansion of $e^{e^{-1}\mu}$. Multiply by $e^{-\mu}$. We get $e^{-\mu(1-e^{-1})}$, which is not equal to $e^{-\mu}$. So $e^{-X}$ is not an unbiased estimator of $e^{-\mu}$.